# How to configure sudoers with path wildcards?

Tags: unix, sudo

I need sudo for a command for any path under a particular area.  Example:

```
sudo mycommand /opt/apps/myapp/...
```

What is the sudoers syntax to allow this command to run in any path that falls under /opt/apps/myapp?  This is Solaris 10 sudo.

---

Thank you for your reply, but I don't need wildcards for the path to the commands, but wildcards for the arguments for the commands.

For example, we want to do something like...

```
sudo mycmd /opt/userarea/area1
sudo mycmd /opt/userarea/area1/area2
sudo mycmd /opt/userarea/area1/area2/area3
```

So far, using wildcards for the arguments in sudoers look like this:

```
/opt/userarea/*
/opt/userarea/*/*
```

And it seems like if we want to have N levels of directories, then we need N lines in sudoers! Is there a better way to include all N levels in one line in sudoers? Thanks.

Comment: @CLee: you'll need to register an account here on Super User, then associate your Stack Overflow account via your profile -> accounts tab.  email team@superuser.com if you need assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Sudo is controlled by the file `/etc/sudoers` which tells it what it can and can't do. I don't know if you can achieve what you want to for the very reason I mentioned below, however, you can create a group of commands like so:

```
Cmnd_Alias TESTAPPS = /opt/dev/myapp/myapp1, /opt/dev/myapp/myapp2
```

You can then allow certain groups the ability to run sudo using just these commands. I have this set in mine:

```
root    ALL=(ALL)       ALL
%wheel  ALL=(ALL)       ALL
```

You could also add to that:

```
%development    ALL=(TESTAPPS)   ALL
```

Confusingly, the ALL in the first case indicates ALL hosts you are logging in from, so you can prevent sudo being run from certain hosts.

Just a quick warning - if you do this and enable write access to this area, the user can just copy commands from say /bin, /usr/bin or whatever and run what they like as root. So I could run `sudo /opt/apps/myapp/rm -rf /` and it would work. You also need to restrict where these commands can run.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking to do the same thing and found this (admittedly old) question...

As I researched further I found that the sudoers man page makes it clear that it will not match slashes in a wildcard match for a command/path name.  From sudoers(5) (in the "wildcards" section):

> Note that a forward slash (‘/’) will not be matched by wildcards used
>   in the path name.

It doesn't say it in the man page but I think this is pretty clearly to keep someone with access to run commands in `/opt/userarea/*`from trying to run something like `/opt/userarea/../../bin/sh` which would obviously be bad...

So no, it won't work as you want (and as I wanted) -- by design.

Comment: You should delete this answer so as not to mislead anyone. The original question was about wildcards in the arguments, not in the command. As the man page says: Note that a forward slash ('/') will not be matched by wildcards used in the pathname. **_When matching the command line arguments, however, a slash does get matched by wildcards._** This is to make a path like: `/usr/bin/*` match `/usr/bin/who` but not `/usr/bin/X11/xterm`.